# How to create multiple Python's instances within a Go application

Tags: python, go, interpreter, multiple-instances

Currently I'm doing a project in Golang which need to call to Python.

In Python it's a library of singleton-like instance.

But I can't modify those library because It's too complicated. (for me)

Most thing I can do is wrap it with my own Python script.

So I'm finding a way to create multiple Python interpreter in Go.

Or maybe multiple sub-interpreter in Python.

Which mean I can create many python instance(same application).

Any ways I can do this?

Comment: If I understand you correctly you want to spawn multiple instances of Python script(s) from a Go program.  I would use a combination of goroutines and the [os/exec](https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/) package to kick off and monitor the Python processes on the goroutine threads.

Comment: I think it's an overkill to do that can can become very complicate. Instead, I think you should decouple two languages' code as much as possible and use some kind of broker or interface like @ChrisTownsend suggested `os/exec` package or message broker if it's a distributed system.

Comment: I throw away my go-python bridge. Thank you both of you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Chris Townsend and pie-o-pah said,

Trying to implement sub-interpreter is much more complicate.

Try to create the language interface is make senses to my case.

In this situation `os/exec` is the way to go.

And can even create ssh to remote my python module if my main server is overload.